# Multiple submit buttons, javascript

Tags: java, javascript, forms, servlets, button

I have a servlet with a form and two buttons. One is a Submit button, the other is a Delete button. The default action is Updater.do, but when I click the Delete button, I have a function to change the action to Deleter.do. This works fine. The problem I have now is that when I put in a confirm dialog, if the user clicks "OK", then it does go on to Deleter.do, as I wanted. However, when they click "Cancel", instead of just staying on the page, it appears to go to "Updater.do". How would I remedy this? I tried deleting the default action and having both Submit and Delete call changeAction, but that didn't work. Here is the javascript chgAction.

```
function chgAction(action_name) {
  if (action_name=="Delete") { 
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Person? This action cannot be undone.") 
    if (answer) { document.forms[0].action = \"Deleter.do\"; } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried an else clause that clears the action on "Cancel?"

Comment: I have tried making the action "". The problem is, there is form data, and I don't want the page to reload if cancel is clicked, I want nothing at all to happen. By making the action "" when cancel is clicked, the page is reloaded - and it says the HTTP method post is not supported by this url. So, I would have to change both the HTTP method and the action in the else clause, which means I would also have to change the method each time OK or the submit button was clicked. Even then, the form data would be cleared.

Comment: Hi, can you please post the form code also? I think I have guessed your problem, just want to confirm by looking at your form.

Comment: `out.println("<form name=\"form1\" action=\"UpdateSRF.do\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"return chgAction()\">");`
The onsubmit part, I just added.

Comment: I think the problem is that onsubmit should return chgAction("something"). However, I don't know what "something" should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both submit and delete are submit buttons, just give them different names. The name of whichever button is clicked will be sent with the request so the server can sort it out.

When calling the confirm dialog, you must return false from the listener or the form will still submit:

```
<form onsubmit="return chgAction(...);"
```

and *chgAction* must return `false` as suggested by Nivas.

Comment: What should I put inside the parentheses of chgAction() in the onsubmit?

Comment: Okay, I have figured out the problem but not the solution. I do indeed need to call chgAction() in onsubmit, but I do not know what to pass into this method.

Comment: You said you already had the listener working Ok, so I presumed that you are passing "Delete" from the delete button and whatever else from the "Update" button.

Comment: Didn't realize that I could send the name of the clicked button with the request- thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `return false` to the "cancel" part:

```
function chgAction(action_name) {
  if (action_name=="Delete") { 
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Person? This action cannot be undone.") 
    if (answer) { 
        document.forms[0].action = \"Deleter.do\"; 
    } 
    else {
        return false;    //ADDED
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work although I have no idea why it shouldn't.

Comment: Onsubmit must return chgAction, but I do not know what should be passed into the function.